# C# Calculator: How do i store the answer from a previous calculation to be used again?

Tags: c#

I want to be able to store the answer of the last calculation e.g. 2+4=6, and then apply another calculation to the answer? e.g. ans*2=12

```
namespace calculator2
{
    class KPcalculator
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Since i want the calculator to be able to restart I enclose the program in a while loop
            ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo;
            bool loop = true;
            while (loop)
            {

                // Declaring my variables
                double num1, num2;
                string operation;
                


                // Asking the user for the operation, to call a function to perform that operation
                Console.Write("\nPlease enter an operation you wish to perform (+, -, /, *, ^, ^1/2, !, f-1, log, rad): ");
                operation = Console.ReadLine();

                // Prompting the input of the first number
                Console.Write("Please enter your first number: ");
                num1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

                // Prompting the input of the second number
                Console.Write("Please enter your second number (if no other number is needed please press 0): ");
                num2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());


                // Using if statements to decide which function to call based on the operation, as well as an error message for an invalid value
                if (operation == "+")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(Sum(num1, num2));
                }
                else if (operation == "-")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(Minus(num1, num2));
                }
                else if (operation == "/")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(Divide(num1, num2));
                }
                else if (operation == "*")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(Multi(num1, num2));
                }
                else if (operation == "^")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ToPower(num1, num2));
                }

                else if (operation == "^1/2")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(Sqroot(num1));
                }
                else if (operation == "!")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(Factorial(num1));
                }
                else if (operation == "f-1")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ToInverse(num1));
                }
                else if (operation == "log")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ToLog(num1));
                }
                else if (operation == "rad")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ToRadian(num1));
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid operation");
                }

                

                // Function for addition (Sum)
                static double Sum(double num1, double num2)
                {
                    double resultofSum = num1 + num2;
                    return resultofSum;
                }

                // Function for subtraction (Minus)
                static double Minus(double num1, double num2)
                {
                    double resultofMinus = num1 - num2;
                    return resultofMinus;
                }

                // Function for division (Divide)
                static double Divide(double num1, double num2)
                {
                    double resultofDivide = num1 / num2;
                    return resultofDivide;
                }

                // Function for multiplication (Multi)
                static double Multi(double num1, double num2)
                {
                    double resultofMulti = num1 * num2;
                    return resultofMulti;
                }

                // Function for raising x (num1) to the power of y (num2)
                static double ToPower(double num1, double num2)
                {
                    double resultofToPower = Math.Pow(num1, num2);
                    return resultofToPower;

                }

                // Function for square root of x (num1)
                static double Sqroot(double num1)
                {
                    double resultofSqroot = Math.Sqrt(num1);
                    return resultofSqroot;

                }

                // Function for finding factorial of x (num1),
                static double Factorial(double num1)
                {
                    double factorial = 1;

                    if (num1 < 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error: Can't find factorial of a negative number");
                        return 0;
                    }

                    else if (num1 <= 1)
                    {
                        return 1;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        for (double i = 1; i <= num1; i++)
                        {
                            factorial = factorial * i;

                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}! = {1}", num1, factorial);
                        return factorial;
                    }

                }

                // Function for obtaining the inverse of x (1/num1)
                static double ToInverse(double num1)
                {
                    double ToInverse = 1 / num1;
                    return ToInverse;
                }

                // Function for obtaining the base 10 log of x (num1)
                static double ToLog(double num1)
                {
                    double Tolog = Math.Log10(num1);
                    return Tolog;
                }

                // Function for converting an angle x (num1) from degrees to radians
                static double ToRadian(double num1)
                {
                    double Toradian = (num1 * (Math.PI)) / 180;
                    return Toradian;
                }

                // Prompting the user for whether they want to perform another calculation or want to end the program
                Console.WriteLine("Do you want to perform another calculation? (Y/N)");
                keyInfo = Console.ReadKey();
                // The loop ends if N is selected
                if (keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.N)
                {
                    loop = false;
                }
                else if (keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.Y)
                {
                    loop = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The same way you store anything else; by using a variable.

Answer (score 2):

1 - Declare another variable in the Variable Declaration section that you already have in your code.

2 - After `Console.WriteLine("{0}! = {1}", num1, factorial);`
save the answer into your new dedicated variable.

3 - Use your dedicated variable

kill yourself

as required in your code.

Comment: How would i write out saving the answer into my dedicated variable? I get an error that tells me "a static local function cannot contain a reference to answer" (answer is my variable).

Comment: declare your variables not in the main method but in the class, before the main().
That way your variable can be used not only my the main(), but by other functions where you want to utilize your saved answer.